# Regex and capturing groups

Tags: regex

I have my regex working to the point where I now have two groups of text, group 1 and group 2 - I'm only really interested in the group2 text. In the end how do I get just group 2 to match/display?

`("token":")([^,]+)`

Comment: What language are you using other than regular expressions?

Comment: Then remove the first captured group: `"token":"([^,]+)`

Comment: Right now I'm just using this tool http://regexr.com/ but will eventually take it into python

Comment: You can use lookbehind: `(?<="token":")[^,]+`

Comment: `re.findall(r'"token":"([^,]+)', string)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work:

```
>>> p = re.compile('("token":")([^,]+)')
>>> m = p.match('...')
>>> m.group(2)
```

This will get the content of the second group. (Taken from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html))

Comment: I seem to be having issues with the syntax     

p = re.compile('("token":")([^,]+)','result()')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 233, in _compile
    bypass_cache = flags & DEBUG
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @Tony: Are you importing the re package? `>>> import re`